# How to override list of columns in loop with output from loop?

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I am trying to create a loop for formatting dates in different columns in the same dataframe. Each column can contain different input date formats (`%d-%b-%y`, `%d.%m.%Y`, Excel numeric date formats ....)  I have tried creating the loop as per below codes. It seems that R recognises x as a column in the list while creating a, b, c, d... but does not recognise x as a component of the list when I am trying to override the existing column with the newly created column (`x <- f$f`)

The dataset looks like this:

```
one <- c(43894, 43577, "08.10.20")
two <- c("10/06/20", "30/05/19", 43978)
three <- c(44029, 44036, 44053)
df <- data.frame(one, two, three)
```

Loop is as follows:

```
date_fields_to_be_formatted <- list(df$one, df$two, df$three)

for (x in date_fields_to_be_formatted) {
  a<- as.Date(x, format ="%d-%b-%y")
  b<- as.Date(x, format ="%d.%m.%Y")
  c<- as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin="1899-12-30")
  d <- as.Date(x, format ="%m/%d/%Y")
  e <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
  f <- e %>% mutate(f=coalesce(a,b,c,d))
  x <- f$f
  rm(a,b,c,d,e,f)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with scope.  You are assigning to something (ie `x`) which doesn't exist outside of the loop.  Assign your output to the original data frame `df` which lives outside the loop.

```
library(tidyverse)

one <- c(43894, 43577, "08.10.20")
two <- c("10/06/20", "30/05/19", 43978)
three <- c(44029, 44036, 44053)
df <- data.frame(one, two, three)

for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    x <- df[[i]]
    a<- as.Date(x, format ="%d-%b-%y", origin="1899-12-30")
    b<- as.Date(x, format ="%d.%m.%Y", origin="1899-12-30")
    c<- as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin="1899-12-30")
    d <- as.Date(x, format ="%m/%d/%Y", origin="1899-12-30")
    
    df[[i]] <- coalesce(a,b,c,d)
}
rm(a,b,c,d,x,i)
```

I had to add `origin` to the other lines to get them to run.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used the dataframe example to illustrate the problem. In truth, I have a dataframe with multiple columns of which I want to format only columns one, two, three. Your method works but now I have a vector with the formatted 3 columns. How do I override the original columns one, two and three in the original dataframe with the newly formatted columns in the vector?

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer.  Now the for loop overwrites the original columns from the data frame.  There is no need for a separate list `date_fields_to_be_formatted`.  A data frame is already a list of columns internally.